# SQL Server Job date output different than output in SSIS debug run

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, date-conversion, sql-server-agent

So we have a SQL job which converts data into a certain date output in a CSV file. This always worked perfectly. Recently we migrated to another SQL Server, and now the problem is this, the query used to transform date and time into the specific format we need is the following:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @Date as Date
SET @Date = ?

SELECT [SeqNr] + 100000 as 'SeqNr'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Start_DateTime],104) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Start_DateTime],108) as 'Start_DateTime'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Answered_DateTime],104) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Answered_DateTime],108) as 'Answered_DateTime'
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Term_DateTime],104) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Term_DateTime],108) as 'Term_DateTime'
      ,[End_Status]
      ,'' as 'End_Status2'
      ,'' as 'ReasonCode'
FROM [RAW_DATAVAULT].[dbo].[H100S1_zendeskChat]
WHERE [EndDate] IS NULL AND CAST([Start_DateTime] as Date) = @Date
ORDER BY [Start_DateTime]
```

If you run this and look at the CSV the format is of one line is:

```
372278;01.07.2020 04:25:02;01.07.2020 04:36:36;01.07.2020 05:26:59;Answered;;
```

However, run the same package via SQL Server agent job, and the result is this:

```
372278;07.01.2020 04:25:02;07.0.2020 04:36:36;01.07.2020 05:26:59;Answered;;`
```

And I can't figure out why it switched day month? The locale is 1043 (Dutch), the query even specifies setting DMY as date format, and all it all it shouldn't matter because the conversion is to string.

So what setting in SQL Server is wrong that it changes the output? Even changing the SQL Server language/time settings didn't matter.

I'm a bit at a loss to find the cause of this.

Comment: Depends on language - https://database.guide/how-to-change-the-current-date-format-in-sql-server-t-sql/

Comment: Yes I was finally able to fix it by setting language to something else than US_English with SET LANGUAGE...

Comment: Instead of `CONVERT()` function it is much better to use SQL Server `FORMAT()` function that explicitly formats date and time to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `FORMAT()` function it would be independent of any server settings.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @Start_DateTime DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT @Start_DateTime AS [Before]
    , FORMAT(@Start_DateTime, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss') AS [After]
```

> Output on my machine

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+
|         Before          |        After        |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| 2020-07-09 08:16:54.023 | 09.07.2020 08:16:54 |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: That works better than my solution of changing languages.. thanks!